# What is happening to my Group Key after JsonConvert?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am trying to do a linq group and it seems to be working but when I do a JsonConvert it seems to be lot.

```
public class StatsVm
{

        public int TotalCount { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LoggedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Say I have an array of 10 of those object, 5 of them have a LoggedDate of 2018-02-19 and 5 of them have loggedDate of 2018-02-20

I want to group them by the date(not time part)

```
var d = results.GroupBy(group => group.LoggedDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToList();
```

That gets me an `List<IGrouping<string, StatsVm>>` which is how I want it but then when I do

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d)
```

I lose the grouping key. I guess it might not be valid json or something. But I would like to have something like this in json.

```
{
    "2018-1-1": [
        {
            "LoggedDate": "2018-1-1",
            "Name": "Test",
            "TotalCount": 20
        },
        {
            "LoggedDate": "2018-1-1",
            "Name": "Test2",
            "TotalCount": 1
        }
    ],
    "2018-1-2": [
        {
            "LoggedDate": "2018-1-2",
            "Name": "Test",
            "TotalCount": 20
        },
        {
            "LoggedDate": "2018-1-2",
            "Name": "Test2",
            "TotalCount": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create the result you need, by using a Dictionary.

Sample code:

```
void Main()
{
    // Create dummy data
    var results = new List<StatsVm>();
    // Create dummy data
    var results = new List<StatsVm>();
    results.Add(new StatsVm { TotalCount = 20, Name = "Test", LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) });
    results.Add(new StatsVm { TotalCount = 1, Name = "Test2", LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) });
    results.Add(new StatsVm { TotalCount = 20, Name = "Test", LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 2) });
    results.Add(new StatsVm { TotalCount = 1, Name = "Test2", LoggedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 2) });

    // Creates the dictionary
    var output = results
        .Select(r => new
        {
            LoggedDate = r.LoggedDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            Name = r.Name,
            TotalCount = r.TotalCount
        })
        .GroupBy(group => group.LoggedDate)
        .ToDictionary(t => t.Key);

    // Serializes the dictionary as a JSON string
    var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    // Prints the serialized string
    Console.WriteLine(serializedString);
}

public class StatsVm
{

    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LoggedDate { get; set; }
}
```

#### Edit:

Code updated to format the date as yyyy-mm-dd

#### Output generated:

```
{
  "2018-01-01": [
    {
      "LoggedDate": "2018-01-01",
      "Name": "Test",
      "TotalCount": 20
    },
    {
      "LoggedDate": "2018-01-01",
      "Name": "Test2",
      "TotalCount": 1
    }
  ],
  "2018-01-02": [
    {
      "LoggedDate": "2018-01-02",
      "Name": "Test",
      "TotalCount": 20
    },
    {
      "LoggedDate": "2018-01-02",
      "Name": "Test2",
      "TotalCount": 1
    }
  ]
}
```